# Any way to save object properties to the asset?

Tags: 3d-view, asset-browser, asset

I am trying to make myself an asset library system which includes a lot of technical objects like collision boxes, triggers e.t.c. (basically I am using blender as a level editor for an educational project).

I have picked a nice blueish semi-transparent color for collision boxes, which, if set as an `Object->Viewport Display->Color` allows for a pretty semi-transparent box preview in the viewport mode (if color is set to "Object" in the Viewport Shading tab, of course).

But the problem is that when I save the asset and use it (making sure I save and refresh everything and set the correct color mode before testing) all object properties are getting flushed, which leaves copied instances of the box with default ligh-grey opaque object color.

Is there any way to save the object color to the asset in order to get the preview I want?

I have already tried using color attributes, but their transparency gets ignored. At least they transition to other instances of the asset, which is good, I guess.

I can assume that the reason behind this is that only the data of the object is getting saved to the asset, which makes sense, but could there be a way around this limitation?

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, blender saves object properties only if the object itself is an asset. If the object is a part of a collection that is marked as asset, object properties inside the collection get ignored.